# backtracking Suduko solving, working in C, error in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sudoku

```
class sudoku:
grid=[]
    #using constructor for accepting the grid
    def __init__(self):
        grid=[]
        for i in xrange(9):
            grid.append([])
        print("Enter elements, values 0 to 9, 0 for blank, press enter after each row")
        for i in xrange(9):
            for x in raw_input().split():
                grid[i].append(int(x))
        self.grid = grid
        print self.grid
    #checking whether  the number is legal
    def check_row(self,row,num):
        col=0
        while col<9:
            if self.grid[row][col]==num:
                return 0
            col=col+1
        return 1
    def check_col(self,col,num):
        row=0
        while row<9:
            if self.grid[row][col]==num:
                return 0
            row=row+1
        return 1
    def check_grid(self,row,col,num):
        row=(row/3)*3
        col=(col/3)*3
        r=0
        while r<3:
            c=0
            while c<3:
                if self.grid[row+r][col+c]==num:
                    return 0
                c=c+1
            r=r+1
        return 1
    def navigate(self,row,col):
        if col<8:
            self.solve_sudoku(row,col+1)
        self.solve_sudoku(row+1,0)
    def solve_sudoku(self,row,col):
        if row>8:
                self.display()
        if self.grid[row][col]!=0:
            self.navigate(row,col)
        else:
            ctr=1
            while ctr<=9:
                if self.check_row(row,ctr)==1 and self.check_col(col,ctr)==1 and self.check_grid(row,col,ctr)==1:
                    self.grid[row][col]=ctr
                    self.navigate(row,col)
                ctr=ctr+1
            self.grid[row][col]=0
        return False
    def display(self):
        print "solution"
        i=0
        j=0
        for i in xrange (9):
            for j in xrange (9):
                print self.grid[i][j],
            print 
        input("Enter key to continue")
obj=sudoku()
obj.solve_sudoku(0,0)
```

Image gives the output of the code
[image: output of the code]

Question: The same code is working fine in C, Now i changed it to python, its not working, Error happens when function returns callback, I cant identify the real issue. After First set of iteration its not returning back to the previous function call and execute the rest.
 I ll paste the output here

```
INPUT
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
OUTPUT
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
solution
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 1 2 3 0 0 0
7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 0
3 6 5 2 1 4 9 0 0
8 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 3 1 6 4 2 0 0 0
6 4 2 5 3 1 0 0 0
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Enter key to continue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/johan/Desktop/sudoku.py", line 71, in <module>
    obj.solve_sudoku(0,0)
  File "C:/Users/johan/Desktop/sudoku.py", line 56, in solve_sudoku
    self.navigate(row,col)
  File "C:/Users/johan/Desktop/sudoku.py", line 44, in navigate
    self.solve_sudoku(row,col+1)
  File "C:/Users/johan/Desktop/sudoku.py", line 56, in solve_sudoku
    self.navigate(row,col)
  File "C:/Users/johan/Desktop/sudoku.py", line 44, in navigate
    self.solve_sudoku(row,col+1)
  File "C:/Users/johan/Desktop/sudoku.py", line 56, in solve_sudoku
    self.navigate(row,col)
  File "C:/Users/johan/Desktop/sudoku.py", line 44, in navigate
    self.solve_sudoku(row,col+1).....
```

Comment: It seems like an infinitive recursive call.

Comment: Also would a newline between functions kill you?

Comment: oh lol!
Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom Zych raises an important point, but there are other issues with your code.

- When you reach a solution, print it, but don't continue the recursion. That means that you should either return after printing or place the recursion in an `else` clause to the found solution.
- In `navigate`, you should also make the two calls to `solve_sudoku` mutually exclusive. In your case, if solving the current row doesn't yield a viable result, the algorithm just continues with the next row. That's why you have so many zeroes in your solution.
- When you set the cell back to zero after backtracking, you should do so immediately after the recursive function call. Otherwise, the non-zero data might trip up the checks for other solutions. (It may not be important here, but it is good style to clean up immediately.)
- The code would be clearer if you used the Python idioms for looping instead of emulating C's while loops.

Here's a working version of your code:

```
class Sudoku:
    def __init__(self):
        grid=[]
        for i in xrange(9):
            grid.append([])

        print("Enter elements, values 0 (blank) to 9:")
        for i in xrange(9):
            for x in raw_input().split():
                grid[i].append(int(x))

        self.grid = grid
        print self.grid

    def check_row(self, row, num):
        for col in xrange(9):
            if self.grid[row][col] == num:
                return False
        return True

    def check_col(self, col, num):
        for row in xrange(9):
            if self.grid[row][col] == num:
                return False
        return True

    def check_grid(self, row, col, num):
        row = (row / 3) * 3
        col = (col / 3) * 3

        for r in xrange(3):
            for c in xrange(3):
                if self.grid[row + r][col + c] == num:
                    return False

        return True

    def check(self, row, col, num):
        return (self.check_row(row, num)
            and self.check_col(col, num)
            and self.check_grid(row, col, num));

    def navigate(self, row, col):
        if col < 8:
            self.solve(row, col + 1)
        else:
            self.solve(row + 1, 0)

    def solve(self, row, col):
        if row > 8:
            self.display()
        else:
            if self.grid[row][col]:
                self.navigate(row, col)
            else:
                for num in xrange(1, 10):
                    if self.check(row, col, num):
                        self.grid[row][col] = num
                        self.navigate(row, col)
                        self.grid[row][col] = 0



    def display(self):
        print "solution"
        for i in xrange(9):
            for j in xrange(9):
                print self.grid[i][j], 
            print 
        print

sudoku = Sudoku()
sudoku.solve(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def navigate(self,row,col):
    if col<8:
        self.solve_sudoku(row,col+1)
    self.solve_sudoku(row+1,0)
```

This will keep increasing `row` without limit, and eat all the stack
with infinite recursion. You need to apply the same kind of check to
`row` as you apply to `col`.

Comment: There is such a check at the beginning of `solve_sudoku`, but it doesn't stop the recursion; it continues after displaying the grid.